# merging a stretchable UIImage with a "normal" one

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I'd like to combine two UIImages, one stretchable and one "normal" one. The problem is that if I merge the Images using the UIGraphicsImageContext, the scond image is also stretched (it is on top of the first one as it should be, but stretched). Does anybody know how to avoid this?

Thanks a lot!

calls from my ViewController:

```
UIImage *stretchImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"stretchableLeft.png"]   stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:16.0];
    stretchImage = [self imageWithImage:stretchImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(64.0, 64.0)];
    stretchImage = [self mergeImageWithImage:stretchImage secondImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topImage.png"]]; // only 40x40 Px
```

the two methods are:

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize  
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;


- (UIImage*)mergeImageWithImage:(UIImage *)image secondImage:(UIImage *)image2 
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
[image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(10,10,image.size.width,image.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you're asking both images to draw in the full rectangle. That is causing your second image to stretch.

Try using the image2.size for image2 when merging the images. You'll have to adjust the placement using the x/y coordinate when drawing the rectangle.

```
- (UIImage*)mergeImageWithImage:(UIImage *)image secondImage:(UIImage *)image2 
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
[image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(10,10,image2.size.width,image2.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
}
```